# change time on timer

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I need to change the time in a timer, now I use the standard phone keyboard but I want to switch and use this, but I don't know even its name!

[Here the link](http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/191/lollok.png) to the screenshot I toke

It's used from the system to change the time and alarm

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the [Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com) and use the `TimePicker` control.

You can check [here](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-datepicker-and-timepicker-in-depth--api-and-customization) for some great sample code on how to use the control.

Comment: thank you
anyway i can't use it, i need to change hours, minutes and seconds and i was sure i could use it, i'll create it by myself